# Clang (MacOS 32/64): disable stack frames in some functions

Tags: c++, macos, stack, clang, darwin

Clang [generates stack frames](https://godbolt.org/z/MBY0TZ), even for empty functions, on MacOS 32/64 platforms. In some cases, I need to prevent stack frames from being generated. What attributes should I use?

Comment: Does it do that even for optimized builds? Not just for debug builds?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search reveals the `-fomit-frame-pointer` flag.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XJ42iG)

Comment: That's right. But. I need to get rid of stack frames only in **some** functions!

Comment: I see. I don't think there is an attribute for that. A possible workaround is to move the functions to a separate .cpp file and compile it (only) with -fomit-frame-pointer.